# Error while trying to install ObjectAid in ADT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, objectaid

This is the error I am getting when trying to install the plugin.

```
An error occurred while installing the items session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile,             
phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null -->    
[R]com.objectaid.uml 1.1.6, action=).Failed to prepare partial IU: [R]com.objectaid.uml 1.1.6.

Eclipse Version :  Eclipse IDE for Android Developers   23.0.2.1259578
```

How can I solve this?
I am following "http://www.objectaid.com/installation" link for installation.

Answer (score 0):

First try restarting ADT. If it doesn't help try downloading a zip archive and use that instead of a direct HTTP link.